# AWS Lambda Go function not getting request body when called via API GW

Tags: go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-lambda-go

First off, one might say this question is very similar to [HTTP request body not getting to AWS lambda function via AWS API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41059440/http-request-body-not-getting-to-aws-lambda-function-via-aws-api-gateway) or [Getting json body in aws Lambda via API gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648467/getting-json-body-in-aws-lambda-via-api-gateway)

However, none of these questions address using Golang, and the problem I have been having is finding an equivalent of the `event` parameter used everywhere in the Node.js documentation.

Here's my Lambda Function:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "log"
)

type MyReturn struct {
    Response string `json:"response"`
}

type APIGWResponse struct {
    IsBase64Encoded bool              `json:"isBase64Encoded"`
    StatusCode      int               `json:"statusCode"`
    Headers         map[string]string `json:"headers"`
    Body            string            `json:"body"`
}

func handle(ctx context.Context, name MyReturn) (APIGWResponse, error) {
    log.Print("Called by ", name)
    log.Print("context ", ctx)
    headers := map[string]string{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"}

    code := 200
    response, error := json.Marshal(myReturn{Response:"Hello, " + name.Body})
    if error != nil {
        log.Println(error)
        response = []byte("Internal Server Error")
        code = 500
    }

    return APIGWResponse{true, code, headers, string(response)}, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handle)
}
```

Problem: the `MyReturn` object is not being filled with any value when called from API GW. The line `log.Print("Called by ", name)` results in nothing being appended to the `Called by` string.

Request to API GW:

```
 POST -> body: '{"name":"Bob"}', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

This is being performed in pure JS as follows:

```
const BASE_URL = "https://my_api_id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/";
const TRIGGER_URL = "my_lambda_function";

function toGW() {
    fetch(BASE_URL + TRIGGER_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: '{"name":"Bimesh"}',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

And yet, the exact same body works when testing it from the AWS Lambda console.

Body:

```
{"name":"Bob"}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out, even though I wasn't able to find any documentation on this on a user-facing website, documentation does exist. Read this: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/blob/master/events/README_ApiGatewayEvent.md

Here's the simplest way I've figured out so far to receive data from and respond to a request from API GW:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "log"
)

type myReturn struct {
    Response string `json:"response"`
}

func handle(ctx context.Context, name events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    log.Print("Request body: ", name)
    log.Print("context ", ctx)
    headers := map[string]string{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"}

    code := 200
    response, error := json.Marshal(myReturn{Response:"Hello, " + name.Body})
    if error != nil {
        log.Println(error)
        response = []byte("Internal Server Error")
        code = 500
    }

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse {code, headers, string(response), false}, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handle)
}
```

In this case, the `log.Print("Request body: ", name)` line results in the exact request body being logged. Problem solved.

Note: Also I didn't have to create that `APIGWResponse` object from the question, the `events.APIGatewayProxyResponse` is the exact same thing, already made for you. These objects are all inside this class: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/blob/master/events/apigw.go

Comment: Thank you, this really saved me from a headache :) The only downside is taking an `events.APIGatewayProxyRequest` as an input means writing pure json for the AWS Console "Test" functionality doesn't work anymore - I guess I need to wrap the request somehow, have you found a way around that?